# Alternate form of implicit differentiation answer

Tags: calculus

The question asks to implicitly differentiate $\tan(x+y)=x$.

I get the correct answer of $-\sin^2 (x+y)$. However, the book also says "or you can use $-\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}$".  I don't see how I can construct a proper right triangle to give/obtain this equivalent answer.  Can you assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this you have: $x+y = \tan^{-1}x+n\pi \implies 1+y' = \dfrac{1}{x^2+1}\implies y' = ....$

Comment: Thank you.  I see this now.

Answer (score 1):

Note that from the implicit equation $\tan(x+y)=x$ you obtain $y=\arctan(x)-x$ and therefore
$$-\sin^2(x+y)=-\sin^2(x+\arctan(x)-x)=-\sin^2(\arctan(x))$$
Now by drawing a right triangle with hypotenuse $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ and opposite side $x$ and adjacent side $1$ note that
$$\sin(\arctan(x))=\frac{\pm x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
and thus
$$-\sin^2(\arctan(x))=-\left(\frac{\pm x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)^2=\frac{-x^2}{x^2+1}$$